# Why is my app constantly pinged?

Tags: openshift

I'm developping a small app with nodejs on Openshift and noticed something that looks weird to me:

when I do `rhc tail -a MyApp`, I see my app is being "pinged" about every second:

```
GET / 200 9ms - 170b
GET / 200 8ms - 170b
GET / 200 8ms - 170b
GET / 200 10ms - 170b
GET / 200 9ms - 170b
GET / 200 9ms - 170b
... (and so on)
```

I'm pretty sure there's nothing in my code that would cause this.
Is this coming from the OpenShift side ?

EDIT: Just created a sample app and noticed the same behaviour; so this is clearly from OpenShift.  Now the question would be why ? Any input from someone at OpenShift would by great.

Comment: Is it on the open internet? Are the IPs/machine names something you've had for a while, or could this be some kind of left over from the previous owners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a scaled application, that is the haproxy making sure that your application gears are running ok.  You can change the frequency by sshing into your main gear and editing the ~/haproxy/haproxy.cfg file .