# Openshift - javabean creates every two seconds

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, cloud, openshift

I created an Openshift scalable application on JBossAS but something strange occurs... Starting page refers to bean which contains output from bean constructor. Then I tail and it shows that my bean creates every two seconds.

> ==> app-root/logs/jbossas.log <== 2014/06/13 03:56:25,779 INFO  [stdout] (http-127.9.184.129-127.9.184.129-8080-1) bean created
>   2014/06/13 03:56:27,809 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-127.9.184.129-127.9.184.129-8080-1) bean created 2014/06/13
>   03:56:29,817 INFO  [stdout] (http-127.9.184.129-127.9.184.129-8080-1)
>   bean created 2014/06/13 03:56:31,825 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-127.9.184.129-127.9.184.129-8080-1) bean created
>
> ... and so on

I have not noticed that behavior no localy no without scalable option too.

What hapens? 
I have tried stop, start, restart, reload app but the behavior is the same.

> ### Domain infosearch
>
> Created:            Oct 16, 2013  9:03 PM   ID:                 ...   Allowed Gear Sizes:
>   small
>
> http://service-infosearch.rhcloud.com

```
Domain:     infosearch
Created:    9:42 AM
Gears:      2 (defaults to small)
Git URL:    ...
SSH:        ...
Deployment: auto (on git push)

haproxy-1.4 (Web Load Balancer)
-------------------------------
  Gears: Located with jbossas-7

jbossas-7 (JBoss Application Server 7)
--------------------------------------
  Scaling: x1 (minimum: 1, maximum: available) on small gears

mysql-5.5 (MySQL 5.5)
---------------------
  Gears:          1 small
  Connection URL: mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/
  Database Name:  ...
  Password:       ...
  Username:       ...
```

> You have 1 application in your domain.

Comment: I found an answer here [Why is my app constantly pinged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873153/why-is-my-app-constantly-pinged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is constantly pinged by the haproxy in a scaled application to make sure which gears are alive so that it can route traffic to them, or stop routing traffic if they are down.  You can ssh into your haproxy gear and edit `~/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` to change what url it pings, and change it to just some static page within your application, maybe a static html page or something that will be there if the gear is up, but doesn't do any heavy lifting.  You can also change how often it pings your gears if you want, but that still doesn't really solve your problem.  I would go with changing the url that it pings, it seems to be the most effective solution.

Comment: Interesting idea. It's worth a try. If I change the ping target page as static page, does not it affect the efficiency of HAProxy Load Balancer?

Comment: No, it is just making sure that page is up, and if it's up, your app should be up.